# Why are "About" and "Blogs" displayed above each other?

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists

This Wordpress theme beats me! ;-)

I can't understand why "About" and "Blogs" are displayed above each other here:

http://ourcomments.org/psyblog/it/

There is another blog here with another theme. On that blog "About" and "Blogs" are displayed beside each other:

http://ourcomments.org/psyblog/

I have looked at all the CSS properties I can think of here, like

```
display, ul: list-style-type, li: list-style-type etc.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: All those importants makes me cringe! It wraps because the width is too small. And why it works on the other, just glancing at the page you can see the fonts are different size.

Comment: Ah, thanks @epascarello, that might be the reason. I did not set !important on font specs! ;-)

Comment: That was the reason. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check your #mh1-menu, you set your `width: 115px;`, and please not use !important on all of your css if not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @fxdavidd. I think need to set both the widht and have all the !importants here. My styles have to win over the theme's styles. Or, hum, do I need to rethink that? I could perhaps win by beeing more specific?

Comment: First of all, you need to check where are the #mh1 css declared from. So that, you can edit them or code your own css properly on style.css. No need to win it over mate, just modify them into your needs.

Comment: Not in this case I am afraid, @fxdavidd. I can't have control over the themes here. What I have written is a banner for a wordpress multisite. #mh1 is the banner. It should fit for every Wordpress theme. (Even if not pretty always. ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

On the link provided(first link) the menu css is displayed out of the twentyfourteen's wordpress theme style.css file and inside the html head.

find the css for the menu.

change this

```
#mh1 li {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

to this

```
#mh1 li { 
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    float: left !important;
    line-height: 40px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Genus, but I do not understand why you suggest this. Could you perhaps please explain?

Comment: The UL list li is displaying vertically, only display:inline-block is not enough you might need to float it right or left in order to display side by side. and when you only float:left; it then you may have another problem that the header bar might decrease height and the    line-height: 40px !important; will make sure it displays proper and aligned with the height space assigned for the header section.

Comment: Thanks, I see. But I use "display: inline-block" so I do not need "float" here. In this case there is also no need for a fix height. (That is taken care of in the event resize here.)